# What Exact Version PHP & MySQL from PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, server, version

I Need to know exact version PHP & MySQL for magento Installation Check

I get MySQl Version From Here:

```
//Test What Exact Version PHP & MySQL

echo "<h2>Exact Version PHP & MySQL: </h2>";

$mysql = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
/* Test the MySQL connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

/* Print the MySQL server version */
printf("MySQL server version: %s\n", mysqli_get_server_info($mysql));

/* Close the MySQL connection */
mysqli_close($mysql);
```

**But how can i get exact PHP Version**

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php

printf("PHP version: %s\n", phpversion());

or http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#reserved.constants.core

just:

printf("PHP version: %s\n", PHP_VERSION);

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with PHP, just use the following script and it will display all your PHP information on the page:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Or if you just want the PHP version without all that then:

```
<?php
echo "PHP version is: " . phpversion();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Way  I check exact version PHP & MySQL for magento Installation

```
extension_check(array( 
    'curl',
    'dom', 
    'gd', 
    'hash',
    'iconv',
    'mcrypt',
    'pcre', 
    'pdo', 
    'pdo_mysql', 
    'simplexml'
));
function extension_check($extensions) {
    $fail = '';
    $pass = '';

    if(version_compare(phpversion(), '5.2.0', '<')) {
        $fail .= '<li>You need<strong> PHP 5.2.0</strong> (or greater;<strong>Current Version:'.phpversion().')</strong></li>';
    }
    else {
        $pass .='<li>You have<strong> PHP 5.2.0</strong> (or greater; <strong>Current Version:'.phpversion().')</strong></li>';
    }
    if(!ini_get('safe_mode')) {
        $pass .='<li>Safe Mode is <strong>off</strong></li>';
        preg_match('/[0-9]\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/', shell_exec('mysql -V'), $version);

        if(version_compare($version[0], '4.1.20', '<')) {
            $fail .= '<li>You need<strong> MySQL 4.1.20</strong> (or greater; <strong>Current Version:.'.$version[0].')</strong></li>';
        }
        else {
            $pass .='<li>You have<strong> MySQL 4.1.20</strong> (or greater; <strong>Current Version:'.$version[0].')</strong></li>';
        }
    }
    else { $fail .= '<li>Safe Mode is <strong>on</strong></li>';  }
    foreach($extensions as $extension) {
        if(!extension_loaded($extension)) {
            $fail .= '<li> You are missing the <strong>'.$extension.'</strong> extension</li>';
        }
        else{   $pass .= '<li>You have the <strong>'.$extension.'</strong> extension</li>';
        }
    }

    if($fail) {
        echo '<p><strong>Your server does not meet the following requirements in order to install Magento.</strong>';
        echo '<br>The following requirements failed, please contact your hosting provider in order to receive assistance with meeting the system requirements for Magento:';
        echo '<ul>'.$fail.'</ul></p>';
        echo 'The following requirements were successfully met:';
        echo '<ul>'.$pass.'</ul>';
    } else {
        echo '<p><strong>Congratulations!</strong> Your server meets the requirements for Magento.</p>';
        echo '<ul>'.$pass.'</ul>';
    }
}


Test What Exact Version PHP & MySQL

    echo "<h2>Exact Version PHP & MySQL: </h2>";
    printf("PHP version: %s\n", PHP_VERSION); 

    ##### Without DB Access 
    ob_start(); 
    phpinfo(INFO_MODULES); 
    $info = ob_get_contents(); 
    ob_end_clean(); 
    $info = stristr($info, 'Client API version'); 
    preg_match('/[1-9].[0-9].[1-9][0-9]/', $info, $match); 
    $gd = $match[0]; 
    echo '</br>MySQL:  '.$gd.' <br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two function in php to get exact version of PHP and MySql.

- For PHP version

  ```
  phpversion();
  ```
- For MySql version

  ```
  mysql_get_server_info();
  ```

Ref:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-get-server-info.php

Comment: Regarding `mysql_get_server_info();`: This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.